How can I make the menu items hide in the submenu when the screen width is reduced?
I have a horizontal menu. When the screen is getting reduced and when a menu item does not fit my menu, this item should be placed in a submenu. The “More” menu item appears instead of menu item. I can click on it and open this submenu.
I mean something like this:

I guess I should watch for overflow and when there is overflow I should cut the item out of the menu and put it in a submenu. I don’t understand what to do if the width is increased.
I work with vue.

You need to share some code that you have tried.

unfortunately Vue's VDOM doesn't help with that. User ResizeObserver and onUpdated hook to rearrange the menu items
